# Convert subquery to join statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I  have this select statement:

```
select * 
from users u  
where u.user_id in (
    select distinct user_id 
    from user_filial 
    where filial_id in (
        select filial_id 
        from user_filial 
        where user_id = 101
    )
);
```

I need covert this to statement with Joins.

Comment: Why would you do this? As it is, the statement is very easy to read and understand. You will lose this. However, the solution is rather simple: join three tables, 1 x users and 2 x user_filial. You will have to give the user_filial alias names in order to use it twice.

Comment: This is, by the way, an SQL statement. This has nothing to do with PL/SQL.

Comment: A join might not return the same information. Are you sure you want to do that? Btw: the `distinct` clause for a sub-query used for an `IN` condition is totally useless.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT U.* 
FROM
    users U
    INNER JOIN user_filial UF ON UF.filial_id = U.filial_id
WHERE U.user_id = 101
```

Comment: This does not return the same result

Comment: Can you say in words what's the purpose of your query. The upper query was just an example to show you have to join.

Comment: I'm not the one that asked :) But I would think the OP's query returns a user and all his/her colleagues work in the same stores as that given user. Your query is equivalent to `select * from users`, returning the same data once for every store where the user works.

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent query expressed using joins:

```
select distinct u.*
from user_filial uf
join user_filial uf2 on uf2.filial_id = uf.filial_id
join users u on u.user_id = uf2.user_id
where uf.user_id = 101
```